# How to check if a plugin's function exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs-container').tabs({ 
        tabs: '.bar', 
        tabs_container: '.foo' 
    });
});
```

Sometimes the tabs plugin script isn't loaded which causes the rest of the page's js to break due to this error in the console:

```
TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
```

How can I check to see if tabs function exists before attaching that plugin to an element?

Comment: How is the tabs script being loaded?

Comment: Why would you want that? If it’s not loaded, then you need to make it load properly. Silently avoiding the error (putting out the fire) will just make your code harder to debug in the end.

Comment: @David actually its a script shared by 3 different sites located inside an include that they all call, 1 of the sites don't load the precursory tabs plugin because it doesn't need it, this script however is still loaded by the framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if($.fn.tabs) {
    /// .. it exists
}
```